# Enviar arquivo diretamente para impressora via CMD

Tags: impressão, cmd

Alguém sabe como eu consigo enviar um arquivo txt(com comandos EPL) manualmente direto para impressora pelo cmd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode copiar o arquivo para a porta da impressora, assim:

```
copy/b c:\\endereco\\do\\arquivo.ext com3:
```

Supondo que a impressora está na porta COM3.

O `/b` serve para indicar que o conteúdo do arquivo é para ser considerado em sua forma binária, é a forma mais garantida de que seu arquivo chegará exatamente como ele é até a impressora.

Se for uma impressora USB você pode usar a API própria dela para isso, mas provavelmente não será mais pelo cmd, se precisar muito que seja pelo cmd você pode fazer um *pool* de impressão nas propriedades da impressora, para redirecionar para o USB tudo que for enviado para a porta que você configurou no *pool*.

Para fazer o *pool*, vá até as propriedades da impressora, depende um pouco de Windows para Windows como chegar até ela, mas geralmente é pelo Painel de Controle ou Gerenciamento de Impressão.

Marque a opção "Ativar *pool* de impressão" parte inferior dessa janela. Inicialmente apenas um checkbox estará selecionado, selecione também uma porta COM, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aplique as modificações.

<sub>PS: a imagem serve para ilustrar o que deve ser feito pois não tenho uma impressora USB instalada, a que eu uso está na rede.</sub>

Comment: Está na porta USB sim, mais especificamente na `USB001`

Comment: `copy/b c:\\endereco\\do\\arquivo.ext usb001:` não vai funcionar, tem que fazer o pool de impressão e associar uma COM ou LPT para ela. Sabe fazer o pool?

Comment: não, não sei...

Comment: certo, e agora eu faço com o USB001 depois de ativar o pool?

Comment: Você deixa tanto o USB001 marcado assim como uma porta COM na janela que eu mostrei na resposta, daí você passa o comando pra COM que você escolheu, daí a impressão será redirecionada para a USB. Na minha imagem não tem USB001 por que eu não tenho uma impressora ligada no meu computador, a que eu uso está na rede, por isso que essa janela me mostra o IP dela.